# Taking input through console Java

Tags: java

I participate in programming competitions a lot and the most important part of that is taking input from user for that we generally use two things

- BufferedReader
- Scanner

Now the problem is sometimes each of the above while taking input gives following errors
 1. Nullpointer exception
 2. NoSuchElementFoundException

Below is the code for both

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Scanner is

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening so?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in one case, your BufferedReader is null, so `br.readLine()` results in a NullPointerException.

Similarly, you can't call `sc.nextInt()` if there is no such next element, resulting in a NoSuchElementException.

Solution: wrap it in a try/catch block.

Comment: Also, br.readLine() can return a null if the stream is already closed. Both of those classes and the behavior of their methods are well documented in the API docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: But when I'm providing the input myself then how could this be null?

Comment: As @Gus said, perhaps the stream was closed. This is more of a question you ask yourself as you work through an example with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Given the possible exceptions you could do something as simple as

```
try
{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
catch(NullPointerException nullPE)
{
    //do Whatever it is that you want to do in case of the buffered reader being null.
}
catch (NumberFormatException numFE)
{
        //do Whatever it is that you want to do in case of a number format exception, probably request for a correct input from the user
}
```

Note that the reader is reading an entire line from the console so you must also catch a `NumberFormatException`.

In your other case, you can simple use a solution similar to the one provided below

```
try
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
}
catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
{
    //do Whatever it is that you want to do if an int was not entered, probably request for a correct input from the user
}
```

It is good practice to use Exception Handling to manage situations in your program that is based on arbitrary input from your users.